# How to use linq query to get value in datatable

Tags: c#, linq

That consist of 2 columns: roomType and no rooms

So I want to get no rooms value from room type that i have.

In SQL its look like this:
`SELECT no_rooms from table name where roomtype = 'deluxe'`
Result: 2

How to access that in LINQ query and store that value as int datatype?

I only know this code

```
string[] tableName = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(s => s.Field<string>("NoRooms"))
    .ToArray<string>()
    .Where(?idont_know_the_query));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var results = from myRow in table.AsEnumerable()
where myRow.Field<String>("roomtype ") == "deluxe"  
select myRow;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var NoOfRooms= tablename.where(x=>x.roomType=="deluxe").ToList();
   int total = NoOfRooms.count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is just another way of retriving the data rows, assuming that table in your example is a DataTable

```
string expression = string.Format("roomtype='{0}'","deluxe");
var rows = dt.Select(expression);
var strRoomNumber = rows.Select(r=>r.Field<string>("roomNumber")).FirstOrDefault();
int no_rooms;
int.TryParse(strRoomNumber,out no_rooms);
```

This will return you the first no of rooms for the first matching record